# Is This A Thread Unsafe Call?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety

Here Is My Code

```
Public th As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf StartFirstPrint))
Public th4 As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf sendFirstEmail))
```

Here is the code of `StartFirstPrint` and `sendFirstEmail`

```
Public Sub StartFirstPrint()
  Do While thCont
    Try
      Dim frm As New frmPrint()
      'frm.MdiParent = Me
      frm.StartPrinting()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
  Loop
End Sub

Public Sub sendFirstEmail()
  Do While thCont
    Try
      Dim frmSNDEmail As New frmEmail
      frmSNDEmail.SendEmails()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
  Loop
End Sub
```

the **thCont** is a public boolean variable that specifies when to shop those threads.

If I access any control of `frmPrint` from `StartPrinting` and any control of `frmEmail` from `SendEmails`, will it be thread unsafe call?
`StartPrinting` is a public Sub of `frmPrint` and `SendEmails` is a public Sub of `frmEmail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access controls, because you would get an exception because of trying to access controls from a thread not being the thread they are created from. It doesn't makr a difference that the method is inside the Form - it's still called from a different thread.